# Parsing URL encodded XML to UTF-8 using XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with parsing the following XML file:

```
<DataContent>
```

+Bric+++
                        %C3%9Clkeleri+Esnek+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C016178%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C52%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++
                        %26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BEmeklilik+Fonlar%C4%B1+%28BES%29+-+++Karma+%26amp%3B+Esnek+Fonlar%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B+%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B+%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BAllianz+Ya%C5%9Fam+ve+Em.
                        +%C4%B0kinci+++Esnek+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C050458%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C61%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++
                        %26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BAnadolu+Hayat+Em.+B%C3%BCy%C3%BC.+Ama.+++%C4%B0ki.+Es.+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C043109%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C20%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BFiba+Em.+ve+Hay.+%C4%B0kinci+++Standart+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C011639%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C16%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BVak%C4%B1f+Em.
                        +Gelir+Am.+2.+Esnek+++EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C020458%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C15%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B
                        +++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BNN+Hay.+Em.+Kamu+Bor%C3%A7lanma+++Ara%C3%A7lar%C4%B1+Standart+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C033045%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C02%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BEmeklilik+Fonlar%C4%B1+%28BES%29+-+++
                        Kat%C4%B1l%C4%B1m+Fonlar%C4%B1%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B+%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B+%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BKat%C4%B1l%C4%B1m+Em.+ve+Hay.+++Alter.%C4%B0kinci+Esnek%28D%C3%B6viz%29+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C011757%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C31%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BAsya+Em.+ve+Hay.+B%C3%BCy.+Am.+Kat.
                        +++Esnek+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C013884%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C14%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B++%26lt%3Btr%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3BAsya+Em.+ve+Hay.+B%C3%BCy.+Ama%C3%A7l%C4%B1+++Gr.+Kat.+Es.+EYF%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++%26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B0%2C013993%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B+++
                        %26lt%3Btd%26gt%3B-0%2C07%26lt%3B%2Ftd%26gt%3B++%26lt%3B%2Ftr%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2Ftable%26gt%3B++%28Not%3A+Analiz+i%C3%A7erikleri+fonbul.
                        com%E2%80%98dan+al%C4%B1nm%C4%B1%C5%9Ft%C4%B1r.

```
  </DataContent>
```

The output should be:

Bric Ülkeleri Esnek EYF 0,016178   -0,52
Emeklilik Fonları (BES) -Karma & Esnek Fonlar
Allianz Yaşam ve Em.
İkinci   Esnek EYF   0,050458   -0,61
. ve Hay. İkinci   Standart EYF
0,011639   -0,16       Vakıf Em.
Gelir Am. 2. Esnek   EYF   0,020458   -0,15
NN Hay. Em. Kamu Borçlanma   Araçları Standart EYF   0,033045

My XSL stylesheet is:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">

        function decode(s)
        {  
        var encodedHTML;

        var decodedString = decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;lt;/g,'&lt;');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;gt;/g,'&gt;');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;amp;/g,'&amp;');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;apos;/g,'YY');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;quot;/g,'"');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&amp;#39;/g,String.fromCharCode(39));
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;br&gt;/g,'&lt;br&#47;&gt;');
        decodedString = '&lt;html&gt;' + decodedString + '&lt;&#47;html&gt;';

        decodedString = unescape(decodedString)

        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;style([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/style&gt;/gi, '');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;script([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/script&gt;/gi, '');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;\/div&gt;/ig, '\n');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;\/li&gt;/ig, '\n');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;li&gt;/ig, '  *  ');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;\/ul&gt;/ig, '\n');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;\/p&gt;/ig, '\n\n');
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;br\s*[\/]?&gt;/gi, "\n");
        decodedString = decodedString.replace(/&lt;[^&gt;]+&gt;/ig, '');

        return decodedString;         
        }
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:value-of select="user:decode(string(//DataContent))" />  

</xsl:template>
```

when I parse the XML document the output still contains "& amp ;" ... which I need to be replaced with "&", what am I missing?.. I'm using XSL version 1.0 and the transformation engine is MSXML or .Net 1.0

Comment: What's your output method?

Comment: My output method is XML @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your output method to `text` If you're outputting XML, the processor must escape the ampersand characters (unless you instruct it to disable output escaping).

Comment: changing the output method to text would work but I want to output it as XML ... @michael.hor257k

Comment: The output that you show us is text. And, as I said, XML cannot contain an unescaped ampersand character. So what you want makes no sense to me.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... I have changed the output method to text also and it didn't give the result I was expecting so I used CDATA instead, and it worked. many thanks @michael.hor257k